# Incremental build in TFS 2017 - How to build only code that has changed from the last build?

Tags: tfs

We are currently building an incremental build but it is building all the projects in the proj file regardless of if those projects have changed.  Is there a way that a script can be written that would pull out only what has changed and checked in or more of an actual incremental build?
When I build a solution, I should only get the changed dlls not all (which includes Microsoft and other 3rd party dlls which are never changed.
TFS 2017 always delivered all files - changed and unchanged, but I need only changed.

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```xml
<PropertyGroup> 
  <SkipClean>true</SkipClean> 
  <SkipInitializeWorkspace>true</SkipInitializeWorkspace>
  <ForceGet>false</ForceGet> 
  <IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried this, but not working                                                                  
<PropertyGroup>     
<SkipClean>true</SkipClean>     
<SkipInitializeWorkspace>true</SkipInitializeWorkspace>     
<ForceGet>false</ForceGet>
<IncrementalBuild>true</IncrementalBuild> 
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: What you describe is **not how building .NET applications works**. It doesn't work that way when you build locally, it won't work that way when you build during CI. The build process might not *generate* new assemblies, but it will always give you the complete set of assemblies necessary to run your application.

Comment: my team wants that they need difference between old build artifacts and checkin build artifacts and they want to deploy only checkin file artifacts dlls. Is there any solution for these?Mr.Daniel Mann

Comment: @naguparimi Check answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051192/incremental-builds-issue-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: Is there any powershell script which can query the TFS and get the changed cs/vb name from where we can develop a logic to leave assembly  with those names and remove the others.